Existence of allah swt
So I was just surfing the web. I was typing the number keys in my keyboard. Then suddenly a question appeared in mind. "Can Allah swt change the laws of maths and how it works?"
I found an agnostic dude giving the answer below:
"You're question implies you are thinking in terms of an anthropomorphic god. If you buy into this version of god then you will quickly find yourself asking questions that will puzzle you. 'If god is so powerful he could make a huge rock that he couldn't lift, but since he is god he should be able to lift it.' The fact that these types of questions arise is not necessarily due to there being no god, but that you are thinking of god in the wrong way. If you were to think of god as infinite and pervading everything then god cannot change anything because that which includes all cannot change. There is nothing to change into since that would mean that he is currently not something that he could change into. This leads to the concept of non-duality and the idea that the underlying reality has no separation within it. You can't call it a 'oneness' because one implies two. It is neither. Consequently, the idea of mathematics or logic becomes irrelevant at the deepest level of reality. The universe simply is now. You are like a wave in the ocean experiencing itself as separate from the ocean. The wave asks, ‘When and where will I find the ocean? Who can give the ocean to me?’ But the wave was always the ocean, from the very beginning, even in its seeking! It’s the ocean looking for itself. Even within the ocean’s failure to find itself it is still the ocean; every wave is one hundred per cent water. As all the authentic spiritual teachers have been telling us for hundreds and thousands of years, you already are that which you seek.
'The dude in the sky' concept of god is an easy idea to believe in and it is an easy idea to refute."
Idk if my imaan is weak or not but I'm getting doubts. I know this isn't the right place to ask these questions but I'm getting thoughts like what's the point of life or what's point of living. PLEASE someone help me. What do our Islamic scholars say regarding his points?
Jazakallahu Khair.

#1,
there is a debate on the Mathematics being subjective or objective, so that if Allah will change it would that mean He should change the logic behind the universe, or simply how the human being understand it ...
#2,
about what he said about the huge rock, at least Shia scholars have straight answers. Allah is capable of doing anything POSSIBLE. In other words, for anything to happen in the causality there would be two requirements, one is the completeness of the causality of the cause (تامیّة الفاعلیّة الفاعل), and the other the possibility of the event to happen (قابلیّة القابل). Allah the Creator is complete in His power to create, but for anything to happen that thing should be possible to happen, otherwise it will not receive the creation by Allah. A stone that its creator is weaker than to raise and hold it,is impossible to exist, never receiving the creation, so that the paradox never happens. The relevant question here would be about the "possibility" and its criteria. Is there any possibility against the will of Allah? No! What then? Allah Himself has Willed what be possible and what not to be, and this is called His Will (ارادة/مشیّة/ابداع) in the Hadeeth by Imam Ridha PBUH. So that any possibility against his Will, would mean a will of Allah against His will, which is what is really asked by such questions: can a will of Allah contradict another will of himself? The answer now is easy: No! Allah is the Wise, and the all-knowing, and not limited to time, and never changes in the course of time, and so would be His will. So Mathematics whether is objective or subjective would be constant as long as the universe and human being is constant, and if Allah changes His Creation for example by altering the universe and human being nature, that would probably cause a change in Mathematics as well, like e.g. some believe it would be somewhat different in the Heaven in the Hereafter. I will not advertise such a view personally, as to me, Mathematics is not a singly system of mathematics, nowadays we have several logics and several system of Mathematics. There have been so many famous Mathematicians mocking at Cantor's set theory, for it talking about different infinities, but people can argue that maybe they themselves had not understood the notion of infinity properly. So that even in Dunya, it is still possible that Jesus the Christ PBUH feeds a lot of people with a single fish and bread, so that all of those people eat from it and the food is yet enough, like e.g. 1=100 or more. In set theory there is a theory called Banch-Tarsky which is sometimes misused by some Math-lovers to explain such Miracles, not a real example in my view but interesting to give you some insight about what is usually being considered impossible, while it might be at the same time also possible in the view of those who have enough knowledge.
PS. The wave example of your friend is widely accepted as a good example for how is the relation between the creation of Allah and His creatures. Although maybe different scholars have different view on it but the example is anyway accepted as a relevant one, no matter how it would be interpreted then.
